# Deployed mvc app not including sitename in href links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have an asp.net MVC web app using Kendo UI Grids with client templates.  The client template specifies an href as follows:

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='[controller]/[action]/[parameters]' />")
```

In a debug run, the link is correctly generated as follows:

```
http://localhost:[port]/[Controller]/[Action]?[parameters]
```

works beautifully.

However, in a deployed environment, the link generated is as follows:

```
http://[server]/[Controller]/[Action]?[parameters]
```

And that fails because it is missing the website name.  So what I need is for it to generate the links as follows:

```
http://[server]/[WebSite]/[Controller]/[Action]?[parameters]
```

How do I need to specify my href links for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hand-code your url's instead of use the [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492942%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which will take care of including the virtual directory into your urls:

```
.ClientTemplates(string.Format("<a href='{0}' />", 
                     Url.Action("action", "contoller", new { param1, param2})))
```

If you want to use the client template value in the url you have to build the url dynamically because the Kendo UI template syntax won't inside the route value:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Id)
       .ClientTemplate(string.Format("<a href='{0}&Id=#= Id #'>Click me<a>", 
           Url.Action("action", "contoller", new { someNotTemplatedParam })));
```

Comment: I'd like to mark your answer as correct for the approach you're suggesting, but I'm finding it difficult to get the right syntax.  How exactly do I set a parameter of that anonymous object to the value of the field that the clienttemplate is referencing?

Comment: @ShawndeWet the Kendo UI cliet template syntax don't play nice with the MVC helpers so it is not pretty. See my updated answer.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since you were on the right track.  However, the correct syntax for the client template is this: .ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Edit", "Customer") + "?customerCode=#= CustomerCode #'" + ">#=CustomerCode#</a>");